# JPA- Showing User Role relationships with Many to Many Hashset ENUMs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

My `DTO` is being stored using `JPA Hibernate` and I'm able to store the other fields but having trouble trying to store this relationship for the user.  The `userRoleSet` `HashSet` has `ENUM`s that represent what roles that user has.  Some users with have no roles while someone will have 1 to 3 roles. Each role is different.  How would I got about representing this in my database and using `JPA`? At the moment, the @ManyToMany doesn't work, I miss be missing something else? Essentially, I need to be able to query that specific user in the database and have it return the roles that is assigned to that user.

UserType Enums

```
public enum UserType
{
    ALPHA,BRAVO,CHARLIE
}
```

Default User DTO JPA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class DefaultUser implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long      user_id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String  user_name;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String  firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String  lastName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String  password;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<UserType> userRoleSet = new HashSet<UserType>();

    /**
     * @return the userTypes
     */
    public Set<UserType> getUserTypes()
    {
        return userRoleSet;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param userTypes
     *            the userTypes to set
     */
    public void setUserTypes(Set<UserType> userTypes)
    {
        this.userRoleSet = userTypes;
    }

    /**
     * @return the user_id
     */
    public long getUser_id()
    {
        return user_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the user_name
     */
    public String getUser_name()
    {
        return user_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param user_id
     *            the user_id to set
     */
    public void setUser_id(long user_id)
    {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param user_name
     *            the user_name to set
     */
    public void setUser_name(String user_name)
    {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName
     *            the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName
     *            the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param password
     *            the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@ManyToMany` annotation is used to map an association between two entities. For collections of simple types, the annotation to use is [`@ElementCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html).

PS: you always *read* and *post* the complete and exact error message you get when something "doesn't work".

Comment: The elementCollection did complete the transaction. It made another table but it represents everything with integer. Is possible to see the values as strings of the Enums?

Comment: Do I need to make any additional annotations in Enums?

Comment: You can annotate the userRoleSet with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, as you would on an enum field.

Comment: Two questions. I think this goes back to what I posted first.  The keys on the user role set table doesn't correspond to the correct user_ID which is the primary key on users table. I need to make sure that they have a relationship.  The right amount of entries are there in the user role set table but it seems that first user that I persist also is key for every user within that test.  My second question is how would I label the columns for the user role set table? Its gets defaulted by JPA when the table gets created.

Comment: Using `@JoinColumn` and `@Column` annotations. Regarding the bug in your code, I don't really understand your explanation, and I can't explain it without seeing the code. This goes well beyon your original question. Ask another one, explaining clearly what the problem is, and containing the relevant code.

Comment: Okay I open another posting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466984/jpa-secondary-table-is-not-using-forgein-key-as-primary-key